# Alternative of vscode.window.onDidWriteTerminalData

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The `vscode.window.onDidWriteTerminalData` event cannot be used when publishing extensions for Visual Studio Code. Does anyone know of an alternative method to capture the text and changes from the built-in terminal to handle this information in a variable?

Comment: where in the VSC API is this defined

Comment: When I run my extension, VSC shows me an error:
Failed to activate extension 'xxx.xxxx': Extension 'xxx.xxxx' CANNOT use API proposal: terminalDataWriteEvent. Its package.json#enabledApiProposals property declares: [] but NOT terminalDataWriteEvent. The missing proposal MUST be added and you must start in extension development mode or use the following command line option: --enable-proposed-api xxx.xxxx. In the link https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api, it says that it is available for Insiders distribution and cannot be used in published extensions.

Comment: did you manage to publish for Insiders, if they have added the proposed API, most likely there is no other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

searching in some places, I checked a NodeJs library called child_process and imported it into my project, after that, I declared a Promise to check the result of the exec method of this library. It was possible to get the execution data and treat it using a regexp to match a text or URL in the terminal.

Example:

```
function runApp(command) {
  setApplicationProperties();
  outputChannel.show();
  let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Running App '${application_name}'...`);   
    let result = child.exec(command, {cwd: getWorkspaceDir()});
    result.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        outputFilter = data;
        infoCatcher = outputFilter.match(/\w.+/gi);
        if(infoCatcher != null) outputChannel.append(`${infoCatcher[0]}\n`);
        urlCatcher = outputFilter.match(/(http|https)?:\/\/.+/gi);
        if(urlCatcher != null) vscode.env.openExternal(vscode.Uri.parse(urlCatcher[0]));
        resolve(); 
    });
});
return promise;
```

}

Thanks for the help.